# Relaunch application when its coming to foreground

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

There is a property called `Application does not run in background` and if we set it to `YES`, the application will end when it goes to the background. But I am unable to find this attribute. Can someone tell me where this setting is located ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an option in the app's plist info file. You have to add it "Application does not run in background"

Set it to YES.